# Why is the time variable in a PDE treated differently than space variables when solving numerically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics

When trying to solve PDEs numerically, we employ methods like finite element method or method of lines. In method of lines we usually discretise in space and then solve the subproblems using a time-integration method for solving ODEs.

My question is, **why is the time variable in a PDE given special treatment?**

For instance:

1. Couldn't you use space-time elements in the finite element method?
2. The initital condition may be treated as a boundary condition
3. In the wave equation: $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$, we have a lot of symmetry in space and time. Why not treat them both as space?

Possible reasons for this may be:

1. Physically it makes sense to somehow use an ODE solver, as evolution time is always dependent on the past, not the future, as we might have with forward finite differences.
2. PDEs with half-infinite domains are difficult to solve numerically.

I understand that an answer to this question might not be a simple one, it may even be just convention.
I checked for duplicate questions, but I might have missed one. Feel free to direct me to the appropriate question if such a question exists.

Comment: The main reason is efficiency both in terms of computational resources and of human implementation time.

Comment: Hi Timur, could you maybe elaborate a bit more on what you mean? Why would it be more efficient to treat them differently? And what do you mean with human implementation time? Perhaps you mean it is easier to grasp when treating space and time differently?

Comment: Even if we treat $t$ as some other 'type' of co-ordinate, the boundary or 'initial' data cannot be specified completely arbitrarily. It depends on the classification of the PDE: elliptic (function data on closed boundary), hyperbolic (Cauchy data on open surface), or parabolic (function data on open surface)

Comment: Let us say you have n dimensional space, plus time. When you do time stepping, you only have n dimensional grid to store in your memory. In a spacetime scheme, you have n+1 dimensional grid, which is a considerable strain on memory. You have this problem even before thinking about it in detail.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. This clarifies a lot.